# KDE - Launch All Applications to the Screen Where the Mouse-Pointer Currently Resides

Tags: debian, kde, plasma, kde5

In KDE Plasma 5.20.5, how can I set it so that all applications are always launched to the screen where the mouse pointer currently resides?

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=156222).

Settings > Window Management > Window Behavior > Multiscreen behavior > Active screen follows mouse:

[image]